# Record a shoutcast for a fixed period of time

Tags: c#, audio-recording, shoutcast, internet-radio

I have this code, it does the record from a shoutcast but it split it for every song title in a different file. What I want is to have all the record in one file and want to precise the period

```
public class SHOUTcastRipper
{
    private SHOUTcastRipper()
    {
        // No objects of this class allowed
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // http://relay.pandora.radioabf.net:9000
        String server = "http://radio.mosaiquefm.net:8000/mosalive";
        String serverPath = "/";

        String destPath = "A:\\";           // destination path for saved songs

        HttpWebRequest request = null; // web request
        HttpWebResponse response = null; // web response

        int metaInt = 0; // blocksize of mp3 data
        int count = 0; // byte counter
        int metadataLength = 0; // length of metadata header

        string metadataHeader = ""; // metadata header that contains the actual songtitle
        string oldMetadataHeader = null; // previous metadata header, to compare with new header and find next song

        byte[] buffer = new byte[512]; // receive buffer

        Stream socketStream = null; // input stream on the web request
        Stream byteOut = null; // output stream on the destination file

        // create web request
        request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(server);

        // clear old request header and build own header to receive ICY-metadata
        request.Headers.Clear();
        request.Headers.Add("GET", serverPath + " HTTP/1.0");
        request.Headers.Add("Icy-MetaData", "1"); // needed to receive metadata informations
        request.UserAgent = "WinampMPEG/5.09";

        // execute request
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        // read blocksize to find metadata header
        metaInt = Convert.ToInt32(response.GetResponseHeader("icy-metaint"));

        try
        {
            // open stream on response
            socketStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // rip stream in an endless loop
            while (true)
            {
                // read byteblock
                int bufLen = socketStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bufLen < 0)
                    return;

                for (int i=0; i<bufLen ; i++)
                {
                    // if there is a header, the 'headerLength' would be set to a value != 0. Then we save the header to a string
                    if (metadataLength != 0)
                    {
                        metadataHeader += Convert.ToChar(buffer[i]);
                        metadataLength--;
                        if (metadataLength == 0) // all metadata informations were written to the 'metadataHeader' string
                        {
                            string fileName = "";

                            // if songtitle changes, create a new file
                            if (!metadataHeader.Equals(oldMetadataHeader))
                            {
                                // flush and close old byteOut stream
                                if (byteOut != null)
                                {
                                    byteOut.Flush();
                                    byteOut.Close();
                                }

                                // extract songtitle from metadata header. Trim was needed, because some stations don't trim the songtitle
                                fileName = Regex.Match(metadataHeader, "(StreamTitle=')(.*)(';StreamUrl)").Groups[2].Value.Trim();

                                // write new songtitle to console for information
                                Console.WriteLine(fileName);

                                // create new file with the songtitle from header and set a stream on this file
                                byteOut = createNewFile(destPath, fileName);

                                // save new header to 'oldMetadataHeader' string, to compare if there's a new song starting
                                oldMetadataHeader = metadataHeader;
                            }
                            metadataHeader = "";
                        }
                    }
                    else // write mp3 data to file or extract metadata headerlength
                    {
                        if (count++ < metaInt) // write bytes to filestream
                        {
                            if (byteOut != null) // as long as we don't have a songtitle, we don't open a new file and don't write any bytes
                            {
                                byteOut.Write(buffer, i, 1);
                                if (count%100 == 0)
                                    byteOut.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                        else // get headerlength from lengthbyte and multiply by 16 to get correct headerlength
                        {
                            metadataLength = Convert.ToInt32(buffer[i])*16;
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (byteOut != null)
                byteOut.Close();
            if (socketStream != null)
                socketStream.Close();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create new file without overwritin existing files with the same filename.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="destPath">destination path of the new file</param>
    /// <param name="filename">filename of the file to be created</param>
    /// <returns>an output stream on the file</returns>
    private static Stream createNewFile(String destPath, String filename)
    {
        // replace characters, that are not allowed in filenames. (quick and dirrrrrty ;) )
        filename = filename.Replace(":", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("/", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("\\", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("<", "");
        filename = filename.Replace(">", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("|", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("?", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("*", "");
        filename = filename.Replace("\"", "");

        try
        {
            // create directory, if it doesn't exist
            if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);

            // create new file
            if (!File.Exists(destPath + filename + ".mp3"))
            {
                return File.Create(destPath + filename + ".mp3");
            }
            else // if file already exists, don't overwrite it. Instead, create a new file named <filename>(i).mp3
            {
                for (int i=1;; i++)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(destPath + filename + "(" + i + ").mp3"))
                    {
                        return File.Create(destPath + filename + "(" + i + ").mp3");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How to modify the code to do the job?

Comment: What do you mean with:  and want to precise the period?

Comment: i mean that i want to record just for a 30 min for example

Comment: If you want to record a specific amount of time then you need to know th length of each mp3 part, right? do you know this information? does the header information of an mp3 part tell you how long it is? 

if yes then you can simply add a timeLength counter to your code and increment it each time you add a new mp3 part to it then close the file when its contents are longer than the specified time.

Comment: no idon't know the length of an mp3 because it is a live shoutcast radio some times we don't even have information about what's running.
what I'm thinking about is a counter that stop the function when time is passed

Comment: Why don't you simply measure how many disk space 1 minute of the mp3 stream takes, then you can calculate how much stream bytes correspond to 30 minutes and stop your file write.

Comment: @Siraf, MP3 audio is not always a constant bitrate.  Your assumption is completely wrong.  The good news is that SHOUTcast/Icecast stations stream in real time (with a small buffer out front).  If you record for 30 minutes, simply download data from the server for 30 minutes.  That will get you 30 minutes of audio, +/- 10 seconds depending on bitrate.  If you need exact timing, you have to decode the audio to calculate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution this is the code if any body need it

```
public  void record()
    {
    // http://relay.pandora.radioabf.net:9000
    String server = "http://radio.mosaiquefm.net:8000/mosalive";
    String serverPath = "/";

    String destPath = "A:\\";           // destination path for saved songs
    String fname="test";
    HttpWebRequest request = null; // web request
    HttpWebResponse response = null; // web response

    int metaInt = 0; // blocksize of mp3 data
    int count = 0; // byte counter
    int metadataLength = 0; // length of metadata header

    byte[] buffer = new byte [ 512 ]; // receive buffer

    Stream socketStream = null; // input stream on the web request
    Stream byteOut = null; // output stream on the destination file

    // create web request
    request = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest . Create ( server );

    // clear old request header and build own header to receive ICY-metadata
    request . Headers . Clear ( );
    request . Headers . Add ( "GET" , serverPath + " HTTP/1.0" );
    request . Headers . Add ( "Icy-MetaData" , "1" ); // needed to receive metadata informations
    request . UserAgent = "WinampMPEG/5.09";

    // execute request
    try
        {
        response = ( HttpWebResponse ) request . GetResponse ( );
        }
    catch ( Exception ex )
        {
        Console . WriteLine ( ex . Message );
        return;
        }

    // read blocksize to find metadata header
    metaInt = Convert . ToInt32 ( response . GetResponseHeader ( "icy-metaint" ) );

    try
        {
        // open stream on response
        socketStream = response . GetResponseStream ( );
        byteOut = createNewFile ( destPath , fname );
        // rip stream in an endless loop
        while ( byteOut . Length <1024000) // 23650000 ~ 30 min     
            {
            // read byteblock
            int bufLen = socketStream . Read ( buffer , 0 , buffer . Length );
            if ( bufLen < 0 )
                return;

            for ( int i=0 ; i < bufLen ; i++ )
                {
                  if ( count++ < metaInt ) // write bytes to filestream
                        {
                        if ( byteOut != null ) // as long as we don't have a songtitle, we don't open a new file and don't write any bytes
                            {
                            byteOut . Write ( buffer , i , 1 );
                            if ( count % 100 == 0 )
                                byteOut . Flush ( );
                            }
                        }
                    else // get headerlength from lengthbyte and multiply by 16 to get correct headerlength
                        {
                        metadataLength = Convert . ToInt32 ( buffer [ i ] ) * 16;
                        count = 0;
                        }
                   }
                }
            }

    catch ( Exception ex )
        {
        Console . WriteLine ( ex . Message );
        }
    finally
        {
        if ( byteOut != null )
            byteOut . Close ( );
        if ( socketStream != null )
            socketStream . Close ( );
        }
    }
```